# clean the json file and structure it into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the code below that is generating the following error: Am I doing anything wrong?

```
*KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-561c05f0fdd1> in <module>
----> 1 venues = results['response']['groups'][0]['items']
      2 
      3 nearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON
      4
      5 # filter columns
KeyError: 'groups'*
```

```py
venues = results['response']['groups'][0]['items']

nearby_venues = json_normalize(venues) # flatten JSON

# filter columns
filtered_columns = ['venue.name', 'venue.categories', 'venue.location.lat', 'venue.location.lng']
nearby_venues =nearby_venues.loc[:, filtered_columns]

# filter the category for each row
nearby_venues['venue.categories'] = nearby_venues.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

# clean columns
nearby_venues.columns = [col.split(".")[-1] for col in nearby_venues.columns]

nearby_venues.head()
```

Comment: The error seems clear. The `groups` doesn't exist in the dictionary. Can you provide more info about the `results` variable? The problem is in the very first line of code. Without more context, we can't know what's happening.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do/don't you understand from the error message?